# Dll import/export

Tags: c++, dll

I have inherited a Linux project that I need to port to Windows and Visual Studio. I have setup the same project structure as was the case in Linux but I find the structure a bit strange (maybe it is all good in Linux) and I believe that's what's causing the LNK4217 (locally defined symbol 'symbol' imported in function 'function') and C4273 ('function' : inconsistent DLL linkage) warnings I receive. I would like some advice on how to re-structure the project or change the code to avoid these warnings. Basically this is what I have:

- Dll project called Foo
- Dll project called Bar (depends on the Foo dll)

The part that I find strange and what I believe causes the LINK4217 and C4273 warnings is that both the Foo and Bar library contain the header and source file for the class `MyClass` (the warnings mention this class):

```
//MyClass.h
class BAR_API MyClass
{
    //Methods etc.
}
```

Where `BAR_API` is defined as `__declspec(dllexport)` in the Bar library while in the Foo library it is `__declspec(dllimport)` according to:

```
#ifdef BAR_EXPORTS
#define BAR_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define BAR_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

How do you propose I change this? Would it help to move MyClass to its own library and have Foo and Bar include it or change so that `BAR_API` is defined as nothing instead of `__declspec(dllimport)` in the Foo library?

Comment: So Bar depends on Foo... but Foo uses MyClass from Bar? MyClass should be defined once (in a third project if need be).

Comment: Yes, but as the solution is setup now Foo would not need to import from Bar since it also contains the header and source files for MyClass. But I guess Foo tries to import it since BAR_API is defined as __declspec(dllimport).

Comment: Basically, I'd leave only one version of MyClass (both header and source) - in Foo.dll project (should be exported using similar FOO_API). Then you should include that header from Bar and link Bar with Foo.lib (the Foo's import library).

Comment: You get LNK4217 when you build Bar but BAR_EXPORTS is not #defined.  It is not very happy that it saw a dllimport for the class but discovers a definition for the class anyway.  C4273 is much the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what you have here
1. `Foo.dll` that defines `MyClass` and exports it
2. `Bar.dll` that depends on `Foo.dll`, but also defines `MyClass` - and this is the source of ambiguity that confuses your linker.

The right thing, to my understanding, is to:

1. Define `MyClass` in `Foo.dll` (since `Bar.dll` already depends on it) and export `MyClass` using `__declspec(dllexport)` in `Foo.dll`'s `MyClass` declaration.
2. `#include` header file that declares `MyClass` (where it will be specified as imported using `__declspec(dllimport)`) where appropriate in the `Bar.dll`'s `.cpp` files; however, do not include the `.cpp` file that implements `MyClass`.

`BAR_API` (which in this case should be renamed to FOO_API) helps you achieve this by being defined as either `dllexport` or `dllimport` based on whether `BAR_EXPORTS` (which in this case should be renamed to `FOO_EXPORTS`) is defined. You should `#define FOO_EXPORTS` in every source file in the Foo project either by setting compiler command line parameter or by #including common header that `#defines FOO_EXPORTS` in every `.cpp` file in the Foo project (but not in the Bar project).

This way both Foo.dll and Bar.dll will use MyClass from the Foo.dll.

HTH

Comment: It is actually Bar.dll that exports MyClass because the MyClass header and source files are located with the rest of the Bar.dll's  source code. But I guess I could make the changes you propose anyway.

Comment: If you don't want to introduce circular dependency, and leave the dependency Bar.dll has on Foo.dll, you will need to place the class in Foo or, alternatively, place it in both and avoid exporting/importing it